# DotNetZip - rename file entry in zip file while compressing

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, dotnetzip

Using DotNetZip, is it possible to compress a file such that the zip lists a different file name for a file than the file name on disk?  For example, I want to add myFile.txt to a zip file, but I want it to be called otherFile.txt.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From the DotNetZip FAQ:

[Add an entry, overriding its name in the archive](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples)

```
  using (ZipFile zip1 = new ZipFile())
  {
      zip1.AddFile("myFile.txt").FileName = "otherFile.txt"; 
      zip1.Save(archiveName);
  }
```

Comment: Hehe, we all do it from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

```
        var zip = new ZipFile(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.zip"));
        var e = zip.AddFile(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "testfile.pdf"), "/");
        e.FileName = "PewPewGotcha.pdf";
        zip.Save();
```

Once the ZipFile is saved, the name is updated.